# Why do all Minecraft launchers crash on my system after being run?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

The new launcher slows down everything tremendously after going through the first time setup, then it sometimes pulls up the launcher and sometimes leaves the screen as it was before the setup finished, but always stops responding to all interactions after this. All older launchers simply slow down everything tremendously and then stop responding to any interactions after pulling up the main launcher page. This has prevented me from playing the game on this computer only, but I can still manage to play the game from the website with the web applet. I have already cleared my .minecraft folder, have reinstalled the latest version of Java, have run from a new computer profile, have removed my computer's antivirus, and have restarted my computer with no affect.

Here are my specs:

- MSI GE60
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Java v1.7.0_25-b17

This has been told to me time and time again that it isn't a bug with Minecraft, but I can't find any way of solving it aside from possibly reformatting my computer. Another thing to note is no error logs, crash messages, or the like are found because Minecraft never actually crashes. I am hoping someone can provide me with a fix for this that I haven't tried aside from reformatting my computer entirely.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking into [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-117-mods-options-profiles-news/).

Comment: I tried this and it unfortunately didn't work. Although that's odd considering the FTB launcher does work, too bad you can't play vanilla with that.

Comment: It could be that you need to clean your pc if it is cluttered getting rid of junk helps. If that doesn't work then try looking through the files of the uploader there could be something that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Following the newest update to the Magic launcher it seems to work, it's weird because it has the same problem with slowing down the system after being run, but after it finally does open the interface on Magic launcher works just fine. And after logging in, so does Minecraft. I just had to get a 1.7.4 Minecraft folder to use it, so I got one from a friend. Thanks for suggesting it in the first place! (Regular launchers still don't work for the same reason)

Comment: Could you run the Java file from the command line and show us the output?

Comment: try updating to Java 8. Also, assign more RAM for JAVA to use. this should help with the slowdown (happened to me too). Not placing this as an answer but as advice since not everyone's pc has the same architecture

Comment: I feel as if this question might be too localised to be honest, however it's quite old now.

Comment: @Ethan722 Actually there is Vanilla Minecraft on the FTB launcher. See [this](http://ftbwiki.org/images/thumb/4/49/Ftblauncher2.jpg/300px-Ftblauncher2.jpg) image

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphics drivers. For an AMD card, use the [AMD Drive Autodetect](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/auto_detect.aspx). For NVIDIA, [the equivalent](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-uk). You might have an [Intel-based graphics unit](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics) instead.

If you're not sure what kind you've got, press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type

> devmgmt.msc

Check under the "Display Adapters" tab. You should see something along the lines of `AMD Radeon HD XXXX` or `NVIDIA ...` or `Intel ...`. Based on which you have, download the corresponding tool.

Comment: I did actually have an update for my Nvidia and my Intel graphics cards drivers, but after installing them I was still unable to play Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this and it unfortunately didn't work. Although that's odd considering the FTB launcher does work, too bad you can't play vanilla with that.

Try the Technic Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Re you sure you didn't delete anything from the Minecraft folder in %appdata% ? ive had has this before so i redownloaded Minecraft with all its folder junk and then, voilà! it worked! and it might work for you!